# Gather inserted text values from multiple rows in a report

Tags: database, oracle-apex

I'm currently struggling with Oracle Apex.
I'm trying to create an application which enables customers to place their order. Therefore I create a report which lists the available products. Furthermore the report contains a column (the SQL query for that is simply `'0' as "Quantity"`) which displays a text box. In this text boy the customer should be able to insert the required quantity.

I've create a screenshot to make it easier to follow me:
[image]

After the customer has fill out the form, the "Place Order" button will purchase the wished items then.

My question is now, how is it possible to read out in which text boxes did the user filled in a number and also to which product belongs it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier solution would be to recreate the region but choose Form Region and then Tabular Form Region and then the wizard will help take care of the DML for you. But you need to use specific table columns for this to work.

To answer your question more directly - the input items defined in reports that are posted to the server can be accessed in PL/SQL as a set of "Global Arrays". These are defined as PL/SQL tables in the package apex_application with the names g_f01 through g_f50.

To be sure which of these arrays to use for the quantity text box you can look at the html of the page for the name attribute of the input tag. If it is f01 then you would be able to process the results by accessing each position or element in apex_application.g_f01.

To link the input with the table you would need some sort of key. If you use the wizard to build a Tabular Form all this headache is taken care of for you though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The problem is basically that the data is spread over different tables. Can I use a Tabular Form anyway?

Comment: You can but the main limitation is that the input elements themselves all must come from the same table or view. If you base the form on the target for insert you might be able to get it to work by editing the query after the wizard is done.

Comment: I tried to use apex_application.g_f01(1) to get the value from the first row. But my text field in which I placed the global variable won't show me anything. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: At this point it would be hard for me to say anything about it. If you identify that the text field is name="f01" and the number you enter in it is in the first row of the report you should be able to access the value when you post. If you enter something in a row other than the first you would need to go get that row number (e.g. apex_application.g_f01(3) for row 3 of the report/form).

Comment: A bit old but this posting includes a package you can use that displays all the values posted from a report with inputs.
http://jornica.blogspot.com/2008/02/apexglobalarrays.html

Comment: Is this actually the right setting to configure for the global variable: http://mhmpl.de/apex.png ?

Comment: Normal page items and application items can be referenced like that in SQL and PL/SQL but for what you are attempting you need to be referencing this within PL/SQL within a Page Process like this:  (https://s3.amazonaws.com/planistry/ONRKSPTOWS/000000020/page_process_g_f03.png)